# IntelliJ IDEA and docker plugin

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am using IntelliJ **IDEA 2017.1.4 with Docker plugin**.
When I click debug, it will build the project, docker, it will start it up and I can see log from the container. Unfortunatelly, debugger is not attached to that container. Error message:

```
Cannot retrieve debug connection: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: tcp
```

When I create new remote debug configuration for the defined port 5001, I can attach to running container. Why it's not attached directly from plugin please?

**My configuration:**
container_settings.json

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "5001/tcp": [
        {
          "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
          "HostPort": "5001"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image][image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue solved.

In IntelliJ IDEA settings - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> open **Build, Execution, Deployment** and **Docker**.

Previously my API url was `tcp://localhost:2375`, and it build and deployed container without any problem, but did not attach debugger to it. After changing to `https://localhost:2376` everything works perfect.

Comment: If you've already checked the box "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" in the Docker Desktop settings, then the URL that works within the IntelliJ IDEA Docker plugin settings is http://localhost:2375 (note protocol and port).
My Docker host isn't listening on port 2376, and if you use https:// after checking the TLS-free box, you get the error "Cannot connect: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Enabled TLS verification (DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1) but certifate path (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) is not defined."